# Tail call optimisation seems to slightly worsen performance

Tags: c++, algorithm, optimization, g++, compiler-optimization

In a quicksort implementation, the data on left is for pure `-O2` optimized code, and data on right is `-O2` optimized code with  `-fno-optimize-sibling-calls` flag turned on i.e with tail-call optimisation turned off. This is average of 3 different runs, variation seemed negligible. Values were of range 1-1000, time in millisecond. Compiler was MinGW g++, version 6.3.0.

```
size of array     with TLO(ms)    without TLO(ms)
      8M                35,083           34,051 
      4M                 8,952            8,627
      1M                   613              609
```

Below is my code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int N = 4000000;

void qsort(int* arr,int start=0,int finish=N-1){
    if(start>=finish) return ;
    int i=start+1,j = finish,temp;
    auto pivot = arr[start];
    while(i!=j){
        while (arr[j]>=pivot && j>i) --j;
        while (arr[i]<pivot && i<j) ++i;
        if(i==j) break;
        temp=arr[i];arr[i]=arr[j];arr[j]=temp; //swap big guy to right side
    }
    if(arr[i]>=arr[start]) --i;

    temp = arr[start];arr[start]=arr[i];arr[i]=temp; //swap pivot
    qsort(arr,start,i-1);
    qsort(arr,i+1,finish);
}

int main(){
    srand(time(NULL));
    int* arr = new int[N];
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++) {arr[i] = rand()%1000+1;}

    auto start = clock();
    qsort(arr);
    cout<<(clock()-start)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I heard `clock()` isn't the perfect way to measure time. But this effect seems to be consistent.

EDIT: as response to a comment, I guess my question is : Explain how exactly gcc's tail-call optimizer works and how this happened and what should I do to leverage tail-call to speed up my program?

Comment: And what is your question? "Explain how exactly gcc's optimizer works and how this happened" or "How do I avoid this issue" or "How can I make the code run faster"?

Comment: Is the first line of data supposed to be 35083,34051 ?  It would be really helpful if you turned the table into a fixed width table, with spaces between.

Comment: What does the assembly look like in both cases?  (Particularly for the recursive calls, but is the first bit identical or not?)

Comment: Caution: this is a bad implementation because the recursive calls can very well explode the stack. Always process the shortest subarray first !

Comment: Without having looked at the details here, it is not a universal truth that `-O2` or `-O3` is the best possible combination of the complex optimization setting the compilers provide for every single piece of code. One can certainly beat the two big defaults by tweaking sometimes.

Comment: @MartinBonner, I have absolutely no idea about x86 assembly.

Comment: @YvesDaoust : Of course, that only helps if the compiler is actually eliminating tail calls!

Comment: @BaummitAugen, part of the reason I implemented this was to see effect of tail-call optimization firsthand.

Comment: ShihabShahriar: As @YvesDaoust says, the main point of tail-calling in quicksort is not to speed up the quicksort but rather to prevent stack blowup. By *recursing* on the shorter partition and then *looping* on the longer one, you guarantee that the recursion depth is less than the log2 of the number of elements, which can be considered a small constant on most practical hardware. (eg. much smaller than 64)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**On speed:**

As already pointed out in the comments, the primary goal of tail-call-optimization is to reduce the usage of the stack.

However, often there is a collateral: the program becomes faster because there is no overhead needed for a call of a function. This gain is most prominent if the work in the function itself is not that big, so the overhead has some weight.

If there is a lot of work done during a function call, the overhead can be neglected and there is no noticeable speed-up.

On the other hand, if tail call optimization is done, that means that potentially other optimization cannot be done, which could otherwise speed-up your code.

The case of your quick-sort is not that clear cut: There are some calls with a lot of workload and a lot of calls with a very small work load.

So, for 1M elements there are more disadvantages from tail-call-optimization as advantages. On my machine the tail-call-optimized function becomes faster than the non-optimized function for arrays smaller than `50000` elements.

I must confess, I cannot say, why this is the case alone from looking at the [assembly](https://godbolt.org/g/Un9ovr). All I can understand, is that the resulting assemblies are pretty different and that the `quicksort` is really called once for the optimized version.

There is a clear cut example, for which tail-call-optimization is much faster (because there is not very much happening in the function itself and the overhead is noticeable):

```
//fib.cpp
#include <iostream>

unsigned long long int fib(unsigned long long int n){
  if (n==0 || n==1)
    return 1;
  return fib(n-1)+fib(n-2);
}

int main(){
  unsigned long long int N;
  std::cin >> N;
  std::cout << fib(N);
}
```

running `time echo "40" | ./fib`, I get `1.1` vs. `1.6` seconds for tail-call-optimized version vs. non-optimized version. Actually, I'm pretty impressed, that the compiler is able to use tail-call-optimization here - but it really does, as can be see at [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/g/TV8BbU), - the second call of `fib`  is optimized.

---

**On tail call optimization:**

Usually, tail-call optimization can be done if the recursion call is the last operation (prior to `return`) in the function - the variables on the stack can be reused for the next call, i.e. the function should be of the form

```
ResType f( InputType input){
    //do work
    InputType new_input = ...;
    return f(new_input);
}
```

There are some languages which don't do tail call optimization at all  (e.g. python) and some for which you can explicitely ask the compiler to do it  and the compiler will fail if it were not able to (e.g. clojure). c++ goes a way in beetween: the compiler tries its best (which is amazingly good!), but you have no guarantee it will succseed and if not, it silently falls to a version without tail-call-optimization.

Let's take look at this simple and standard implementation of tail call recursion:

```
//should be called fac(n,1)
unsigned long long int 
fac(unsigned long long int n, unsigned long long int res_so_far){
  if (n==0)
    return res_so_far;
  return fac(n-1, res_so_far*n);
}
```

This classical form of tail-call makes it easy for compiler to optimize: see result [here](https://godbolt.org/g/2ahVMd) - no recursive call to `fac`!

However, the gcc compiler is able to perform the TCO also for less obvious cases:

```
unsigned long long int 
fac(unsigned long long int n){
  if (n==0)
    return 1;
  return n*fac(n-1);
}
```

It is easier to read and write for us humans, but harder to optimize for compiler (fun fact: TCO is not performed if the return type would be `int` instead of `unsigned long long int`): after all the result from the recursive call is used for further calculations (multiplication) before it is returned. But gcc [manages](https://godbolt.org/g/pcjtJU) to perform TCO here as well!

At hand of this example, we can see the result of TCO at work:

```
//factorial.cpp
#include <iostream>

unsigned long long int 
fac(unsigned long long int n){
  if (n==0)
    return 1;
  return n*fac(n-1);
}

int main(){
  unsigned long long int N;
  std::cin >> N;
  std::cout << fac(N);
}
```

Running `time echo "40000000" | ./factorial` will get you the result (0) in no time if the tail-call-optimization was on, or "Segmentation fault" otherwise - because of the stack-overflow due to recursion depth.

Actually it is a simple test to see whether the tail-call-optimization was performed or not: "Segmentation fault" for non-optimized version and large recursion depth.

---

**Corollary:**

As already pointed out in the comments: Only the second call of the `quick-sort` is optimized via TLO. In you implementation, if you are unlucky and the second half of the array always consist of only one element you will need `O(n)` space on the stack.

However, if the first call would be always with the smaller half and the second call with the larger half were TLO, you would need at most `O(log n)` recursion depth and thus only `O(log n)` space on the stack.

That means you should check for which part of the array you call the `quicksort` first as it plays a huge role.

Comment: You did not answer any of the three questions posed by the OP. You did not explain how gcc's tail call optimizer works. You did not explain why that optimization reduced the performance of qsort. You did not explain how to fix qsort so that the optimization works better on it. All you have done here is a general, imprecise introduction to tail call optimization. The amazing part is, despite all that, the OP accepted your answer and you got 5 upvotes and 0 downvotes. People who can actually answer the questions would no longer be motivated to do that because nobody cares anymore.

Comment: @HadiBrais sorry to hear, my answer ruined this question for you, I did my best (there are a lot of people who could do a lot better, for sure), still I hope it was not completely useless for others. If you are interested in a better answer, you can start a bounty or post your own more specific question (because "explain how gcc works" will most probably not trigger a lot of precise answers).

Comment: @HadiBrais or if you would like to give a more precise answer, I would be happy to start a bounty if this would motivate you.

Comment: Your answer is not useless. It is just that this is not the right place for it. I was interested in giving an answer. I don't want any bounty. The OP accepted your answer and moved on. So there is no point in spending any effort on this anymore.